# Maven build failure - first install

Tags: java, windows, maven, administrator, rights

I'm a beginner trying to install and create my first project.
I've installed Maven on windows 8 and I meet problem.

I didn't create a settings.xml file.
This command seems to reveal a problem :

mvn -X :
[image: mvn -X 1]
[image: mvn -X 2]

and if I try to create a quickstart project I get this :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.1
```

[image: mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.1]

I don't find a way to solve this problem even looking at other issues posts on the web, I someone can help ?

EDIT 1 ----------------------------------------------------------------

With tis command :

```
mvn -X archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.1
```

Here are the last debug lines I can, copy/paste here :

```
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : Velocimacro : initialization complete.
[DEBUG] RuntimeInstance successfully initialized.
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) archetypeArtifactId = maven-archetype-quickstart
[DEBUG]   (f) archetypeCatalog = remote,local
[DEBUG]   (f) archetypeVersion = 1.1
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = C:\Program Files\apache\repository
[DEBUG]   (f) interactiveMode = true
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///C:/Users/B/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) remoteArtifactRepositories = [      id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@320a8ebf
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[DEBUG] Searching for remote catalog: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
[DEBUG] Using catalog C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\archetype-catalog.xml
[DEBUG] Not found archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 in cache
[DEBUG] Found archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 in cache: C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apach
[DEBUG] checking fileset archetype status on C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-archetype-quickstart\1.
[DEBUG] Searching for META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml inside C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-a
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/maven/archetype.xml
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/LICENSE
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/NOTICE
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/AppTest.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/App.java
[DEBUG] Found archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 in cache: C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apach
[DEBUG] checking old archetype status on C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-archetype-quickstart\1.1\ma
[DEBUG] Searching for META-INF/maven/archetype.xml inside C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-archetype-
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/maven/archetype.xml
[DEBUG] Entry found
[DEBUG] Found archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 in cache: C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apach
[DEBUG] Searching for META-INF/maven/archetype.xml inside C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-archetype-
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/maven/archetype.xml
[DEBUG] Entry found
[DEBUG] Creating ArchetypeConfiguration from legacy descriptor and Properties
[DEBUG] Adding requiredProperty groupId
[DEBUG] Setting property groupId=null
[DEBUG] Adding requiredProperty artifactId
[DEBUG] Setting property artifactId=null
[DEBUG] Adding requiredProperty version
[DEBUG] Setting property version=null
[DEBUG] Adding requiredProperty package
[DEBUG] Setting property package=null
[DEBUG] Required properties before content sort: [groupId, artifactId, version, package]
[DEBUG] Required properties after content sort: [groupId, artifactId, version, package]
Define value for property 'groupId': org.exemple.demo
Define value for property 'artifactId': mon-appli
Define value for property 'version' 1.0-SNAPSHOT: :
Define value for property 'package' org.exemple.demo: :
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: org.exemple.demo
artifactId: mon-appli
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: org.exemple.demo
 Y: :
[DEBUG] Archetype generation configuration confirmed
[DEBUG] Found archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 in cache: C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apach
[DEBUG] Found archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 in cache: C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apach
[DEBUG] checking fileset archetype status on C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-archetype-quickstart\1.
[DEBUG] Searching for META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml inside C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-a
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/maven/archetype.xml
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/LICENSE
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/NOTICE
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/test/java/AppTest.java
[DEBUG]   - archetype-resources/src/main/java/App.java
[DEBUG] checking old archetype status on C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-archetype-quickstart\1.1\ma
[DEBUG] Searching for META-INF/maven/archetype.xml inside C:\Users\B\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes\maven-archetype-
[DEBUG]   - META-INF/maven/archetype.xml
[DEBUG] Entry found
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: C:\Program Files\apache\repository
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: org.exemple.demo
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: org.exemple.demo
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: mon-appli
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: org.exemple.demo
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 44.131 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-13T12:28:25+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalon
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Error merging velocity templates
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute (CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
←[0m←[0m
C:\Program Files\apache\repository>
```

EDIT 2 -----------------------------------------------------------------

I found the origin of the problem:

The apache-maven-3.5.3 files were in a folder created in c:\Program Files.

I changed and created a directory at the root of c:\apache\apache-maven-3.5.3 and the script now works without problems.

Comment: Please add Messages as text not as image

Comment: I updated my post with mvn -X result

Comment: Set this `-DarchetypeVersion=1.1` like this: `-DarchetypeVersion=3.0.1`...

Comment: with -DarchetypeVersion=3.0.1 I get "The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:3.0.1)"